# Starting Tomcat as a service on LINUX

Tags: linux, tomcat

I have to use Tomcat to deploy my webapplication. I have copied the installable files and was able to install tomcat. I have very limited privilages on the linux system. I need to make tomcat run as a system service. Can anyone help?

However, when I logged out and logged in to the Linux machine, Tomcat was still running. Is it that we need not worry to restart Tomcat at every login. Any help needed

Thanks,
vamsi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what you have mentioned above, looks like tomcat is already running in the background. If you want tomcat to run as a service, use the steps here 
http://www.spaceprogram.com/knowledge/tomcat_init_d.html

It is possible that tomcat was started as a background process, which explain why it was still running when you logged off and back in.
The advantage of setting it up as a service is that when the server restarts, upon startup it will also startup tomcat.

Comment: The answer's link is dead.